# Multiple string::find

Tags: c++, string, find-occurrences

Is there a way like "if, for loop" or something to search for first and second string, and if there are no string occurrences to search for third one.

I am stuck in with this three. I need somehow to check if there are string "aba" in first and second, but if there are not to check for "aba" in third string. Some ideas? Tnx in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

string s1, s2, s3;
string aba = "aba";


cout << "Input s1, s2: ";
cin >> s1;
cin >> s2;

s3 = s1 + s2;

cout << "String s3 is: " << s3;

cout << "\n\n****************************\n";

size_t found = s1.find(aba);
if(found!=string::npos){    
    cout << "Have for s1.";
}

size_t found1 = s2.find(aba);
if(found1!=string::npos){
    cout << "Have for s2.";
}

size_t found2 = s3.find(aba);
if(found2!=string::npos){
    cout << "Have for s3.";
}


}
```

Comment: Take out a piece of paper. Write down the logical algorithm you propose to accomplish this task, in simple, short, logical steps. Like "search first string. If found do this. Otherwise do the following". And so on. [Discuss your written down logic with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Once your rubber duck agrees that it will work, simply translate the written down logical process directly into C++. Mission accomplished.

Comment: Maybe all you need is an `&&` operator?

Comment: @johnchen902 the problem is I don't get what loop to use, since it already uses IF loop, I can't use it again? I am lost hahaha...

Comment: Uhh... *if is not a loop*, and the *control structures* can be nested.

Comment: @johnchen902 made it work, but your thots on improving it or it is fine this way?

Comment: @Beansolder It definitely can be improved. You really need the `&&` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by best, but keeping your variable names, this is *slightly* cleaner IMHO.

```
if( ( found != string::npos ) && ( found1 != string::npos ) )
{
   cout << "There is for s1 i s2.\n";
}
else
{
   cout << "Don't have for s1 i s2, search in s3.\n";
   if( found2 != string::npos )
   {
      cout << "There is for s3.\n";
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "Don't have for s3.\n";
   }
}
```

The && operator will [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and there is no repetition of the strings in the code.  Should you need to change the strings (although it appears to be a toy example and I doubt it), you could do it in just one place (a minor application of the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).

Comment: Tnx, this looks clean and nice. Mine is all messed up but it works. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Finally did it, but is this best way for it?

```
if(found != string::npos){
    if(found1 != string::npos){
        cout << "\nThere is for s1 i s2.";
    } else {
        cout << "\nDon't have for s1 i s2, search in s3.";
        if(found2 != string::npos){
            cout << "\nThere is for s3.";
        } else {
            cout << "\nDon't have for s3.";
        }
    }
} else {
    cout << "\nDon't have for s1 i s2, search in s3.";
    if(found2 != string::npos){
            cout << "\nThere is for s3.";
        } else {
            cout << "\nDon't have for s3.";
        }
}
```